# Function of "or"

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

> A hot drink that is made with wine, beer, **or** cider, spices, sugar, and usually baked apples and is traditionally served in a large bowl especially at Christmastime (Merriam Webser-wassail)

Is a possible recipe like  this?

- wine, spices, sugar and apples?

Does this *or* cover only wine, beer, cider?

- (wine, beer, or cider) + spices + sugar + (usu; apples)??

Comment: I think it's General Reference that in OP's citation, the placement of ***or*** limits its scope to [one of] *wine, beer, cider*. Also that the placement of ***usually*** limits its scope to *baked apples*, leaving *spices, sugar* as "unqualified" ingredients (by implication, they're *always* present). Any alternative readings would be opinion-based pedantry.

Comment: ... I'd interptet it that way. But since the demands made on the third comma are different from those on the first two, I'd use a semicolon in the super-comma role non-pedants allow.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth so my interpretation is ok?

Comment: I don't understand what you said. A Choose one of: wine, beer, cider. B Add spices and sugar. C (optional, but usually included) Add baked apples. Both your recipes seem to fit these requirements. Jasper Loy's alternative analysis is gramatically possible, but, as FF says, extremely unlikely to be intended by the people at M-W, from pragmatic considerations of the unlikelihood of sugar- and spice-free wassail.

Comment: I've been mulling over this question. Taking into account the unstable punctuation conventions of alcoholic beverage recipes, as well as my own successful experience as a mixologist at a pub/wine-bar in dreary winter months, I would say: Any combination of these (wine, beer, cider) and (spices + sugar) and optionally baked apples.

Answer (score 2):

> wine, beer, or cider, spices, sugar, and usually baked apples

can be interpreted as

> (wine, beer, or cider), spices, sugar, and usually baked apples

or

> wine, beer, or (cider, spices, sugar, and usually baked apples)

One would need more than the language itself to know which the recipe refers to.

Comment: Or indeed as “[wine _or_ beer _or_ (cider, spices, sugar)] _and_ usually baked apples”; i.e., if you use cider instead of wine or beer, you’d also add some sugar and spice, but you wouldn’t if you used wine or beer. This interpretation would have worked better if there’d been an _and_ between “spices” and “sugar” instead of just a comma.

Comment: I would go so far as to say the comma after *beer* is actually wrong as introducing ambiguity, but others may disagree.

Comment: ... Or 'wine, (beer or cider), spices, ...'